# How to minify inline JavaScript functions with a JSP tag?

Tags: javascript, jsp, yui, minify

In this JSP fragment file the second inline -block is correctly minified. But the first block is completely empty when using compression. I found out that this happens as soon as the inline JavaScript contains a function declaration. Is there any way of minifying those function declarations without needing to put them into an external .js?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://htmlcompressor.googlecode.com/taglib/compressor" prefix="compress" %>
<script>
   //This results in empty output:  
   <compress:js enabled="true" yuiJsLineBreak="80">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //This is not executed
        console.log("Document ready fired " + $().jquery);
    });
    function tester(message) {
        console.log(message);
        return 0;
    }
    </compress:js>
</script>

<script>
    // This is working perfectly: 
    <compress:js enabled="true" yuiJsLineBreak="80">
    //Some comment that should not be shown
    console.log("Minified code did something...");
    console.log("...");
    var a = 1 + 4;
    $().jquery;
    $(document).ready();
    </compress:js>
</script>
```

Comment: Compressing on the fly decreases performance. You'd be better off putting them in an external JS file.

Comment: I assume, using an external JS file and compressing that with a Tomcat Filter has the same performance. Is that right?